# How to read config(.ini) file in python which will work on 2.7 and 3.x python

Tags: python, configparser

Should I use `ConfigParser` which is compatible with python 2.7 and 3.x or do you suggest any other module in python which is compatible with both versions of python for reading config file?

Comment: Apart from the name of the module, what exactly do you think is incompatible between the versions?

Comment: "from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser"
this line giving error in python3 which will work great in python 2.7

Comment: i want to create an app which will work on both the versions of python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`configparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser) backport, so it will work on both Python version.

```
pip install configparser
```

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the other answers here, you don't need to install any extra packages to write INI-parsing code that is compatible with Python 2 and 3. Python 3.0's [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/configparser.html) is just a renamed version of Python 2's [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). There have been some extra features added in Python 3.2 and 3.5 (see the latest version of the docs at https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) but these are backwards-compatible, so if you're happy with the features of Python 3.0's `configparser` you can just do

```
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.x fallback
    import ConfigParser as configparser
```

Comment: This would be more helpful if it made more explicit just what set of features of python3's configparser might be used to maintain backward compatibility with python2's ConfigParser. For example, python3 does not have a SafeConfigParser class (its equivalent is now ConfigParser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `configparser2` [module](https://github.com/shubhamchaudhary/configparser2), which is a fork of the [`configparser` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser) maintained by me.
Add it in your [requirements](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser2) or do `pip install configparser2` and then use something as simple as:

```
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError as e:
    import configparser2 as configparser
```